# Objc-class-ref error in couchbase lite in iOS cocoapods xcode 9

Tags: xcode9, couchbase-lite

Integrating CouchbaseLite in iOS application causing error through cocoapods . Here is error i am getting :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: “OBJC_CLASS$_CBLManager”,
>   referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not
>   found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I also raised issue on couchbase-lite forum : 
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/bjc-class-ref-error-in-couchbase-lite-in-ios-cocoapods-xcode-9/14744?u=st.shubh.tiwari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The “Other Linker” flags was set to “-ObjC”. Change that to $(inherited). That will ensure that Cocoapods is able to include the appropriate flags. Otherwise your cocoa pods install won’t go through fine.

This really helps me to resolve my issue . Big Thanks to CouchBase community.